# Jackson fasterxml UnrecognizedPropertyException happening randomly

Tags: java, jboss, jackson

I have a class annotated with @JsonAlias and @JsonProperty to allow mapping from snake_case attributes to camelCase ones. Example:

```
@JsonAlias({ "pedidoDevolucion", "pedido_devolucion" })
@JsonProperty(value = "pedido_devolucion", required = false)
private Boolean pedidoDevolucion;
```

The problem is that sometimes this code works perfectly when it tries to map from "pedido_devolucion" from a JSON to "pedidoDevolucion" attribute in Java object, and some other times it fails throwing:

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "pedido_devolucion"

The code that makes the mapping is:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;

public static <DtoT> DtoT getDTO(ClientResponse clientResponse, Class<DtoT> claseDto)
        throws Exception {

    DtoT response = null;

    if (clientResponse.getStatus() == ClientResponse.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {

        response = claseDto.cast(clientResponse.getEntity(claseDto)); // this one
```

I know that sometimes Jackson has problems with dependencies, specifically when its mixed with the org.codehaus dependency, but in my case Im using the one from fasterxml on my whole project. 
The Jackson's related dependencies on my pom are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml where I define some modules, and some exclusions that are known to have conflicts with fastersxml's Jackson:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.cxf" export="true" meta-inf="export" />
        <module name="org.jboss.ws.native.jbossws-native-core" />
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" />
        <module name="org.jboss.xnio" />
        <module name="org.hornetq" />
    </dependencies>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="weld" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

Currently the code works sometimes and some others dont. I have no idea why it can be. For the randomly stuff I thought it could be a class loading issue but I dont know for sure.
Please if anyone can provide me some help i will preciate it.

Comment: I hit the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?